# wkhtmltopdf style table of contents

Tags: php, drupal-7, wkhtmltopdf

I'm wondering how i can go about reducing the font size on the generated table of contents.

I've read and reread their documentation here: https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

The bit i'm confused on is:

The generated XML document can be viewed by dumping it to a file using the
  --dump-outline switch. For example:

```
wkhtmltopdf --dump-outline toc.xml http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html qstring.pdf
```

I'm having difficulty understanding how to translate to my own project, and what  do they mean by this part of the command:

```
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html qstring.pdf
```

Comment: Someone said that "you can pass the toc argument and the table of contents will be generated based off of the h HTML tags (e.g. <h1>, <h2>, etc.) in your HTML file. This doesn't seem to require a .xsl file" does that mean I should type in True for the toc argument here? Thank you!
toc = {
    'xsl-style-sheet': 'toc.xsl'
    # 'xsl-style-sheet': 'toc copy.xsl'
}


pdfkit.from_file(
    book_html_filename, book_pdf_filename, 
    configuration=config, 
    toc=toc,
    options=options,cover=cover_html_filename,cover_first=True)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the default table of content (HTML and / or CSS styles), you can use the `xsl-style-sheet` parameter to specify a custom XLS stylesheet.

In your custom XLS you can add any HTML tag you need.

You can find an example of the default XLS file [here](https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport-wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/lib/default-toc.xsl). For your information, le XLS is generated from the `tocstylesheet.cc` file (see [here](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/blob/050dd18d9ed70aa23fb97f8a8b46b5e8a0ad3485/src/lib/tocstylesheet.cc)).