# How to style table of content with wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: drupal-8, wkhtmltopdf

I generate a pdf file from HTML, with the help of Entity Print module and wkhtmltopdf engine. I have an issue that I can not theme the table of content. 
By the similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48016246/wkhtmltopdf-style-table-of-contents) I guess that I need to do it through custom xsl sheet, but I don't know how can I set it.

I have tried in PhpWkhtmlToPdf.php under /* TOC handling */

```
$this->getPrintObject()->setOptions(['xsl-style-sheet' => 'link to xsl sheet']);

$options[] = ['xsl-style-sheet' => 'link to xsl sheet'];
```

But it did not work.

All formatting which I have in entity-print.css affect the whole generated docs, but not the table of contens. Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->getPrintObject()->addToc(array('xsl-style-sheet' => '../entity_print/files/custom-toc.xsl'));
```